# check username already exists in django without using AJAX

Tags: html, django, ajax, sqlite, django-views

I am a beginner in django web development. I want to submit a form in django that will store data in our sqllite database.

I want to let the user know if the student id in my form already exists in the database or not without submitting form. I am not using Ajax in it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mre]. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if student's username is already added or not in your db  then you can do like this  in your forms

First make a `Student` model

```
    Class Student (models.Model):
       username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
         ...........
         ........
```

Then in your forms.py you can check username like this

```
Class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def check_username (self):
        username = self.cleaned_data ['username']
        ifStudent.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
              raise ValidationError('user already exists')
        return username

  Class Meta:
        model = Student 
        fields = [................]
```

Comment: You don't need to do.you can just save the  modelform in your views